# Не получается сделать дамп базы данных

Tags: linux, база-данных, репликация

Работаю в PuTTY, делаю репликацию БД и пытаюсь сделать дамп базы, но он просто не делается.

Смотрела, как делать в примере репликации, смотрела в документации Linux, смотрела в документации 1С Битрикс (виртуальная машина на Битрексе), но ничего не помогает.

Сначала писала так: `mysqldump -u root -p test > test.sql`.

Потом так: `mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD test > /path/to/file/dump.sql`.

И так: `mysqldump -u -p test > /path/to/file/dump.sql`.

И так: `mysqldump -u root -p test > /path/to/file/dump.sql`.

На всё один результат - [image]

Выглядит так, будто я не дописала команду, но на сайтах написано так, как в примерах выше, что ему ещё нужно?

Comment: Судя по картинке, вы вводите команду не в командном интерпретаторе linux, а в mysql

Comment: Да, сейчас вышла из mysql и дело двинулось дальше... я просто всё делала в mysql, поэтому и это тоже... спасибо большое

Comment: Теперь получаю ошибку: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect.
Я создавала пользователя и давала ему права на репликацию. Что тут не так, скажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Делайте подключение под пользователем которому разрешено работать с этой БД. Пользователь root может быть отключен в системе для входа в mysql.

Comment: При попытке авторизации через созданного пользователя система отвечает, что доступ запрещён